# Login Logout System Time is still the Same

Tags: java, timestamp

**Good day!**
I have a problem regarding to this system. Everytime I press log out button, time that I log in is there instead of the current time.

```
 String logout = usernameTF.getText();
            if (logout.contains(name))
            {
                usernameTF.setText("");
                timeouttf.setText(dtf.format(logoutTime));
                sessiontimetf.setText(Integer.toString((int) Duration.between(loginTime, logoutTime).getSeconds()));
                username.clear();
                loginbtn.setEnabled(true);
                resetbtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
                usernameTF.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WRONG INFORMATION", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

Please help me with this. I tried other solutions but it didn't work.

This is the origin of the variables `logoutTime` and `loginTime` since I made this program with JFrame.

```
private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime loginTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime logoutTime = LocalDateTime.now();
```

this is the result when I try to log in and out. (please check out the picture)

[as you see, I log in at 2019/02/24 13:38:36 but when I log out three minutes later, it's still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isC83.png)

Comment: Sorry, it’s not clear. Maybe you can give an example where you tell us what times you logged in and out and the observed values of `loginTime` and `logoutTime`? [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be nice. Then I’m sure we can help.

Comment: sorry for late reply. the time for `loginTime` and `logoutTime` is the same

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You still haven’t given us something we can reproduce, and in your code I can’t see where you are setting `loginTime` (as I understand the variable that has the wrong value). So I don’t know how to help you.

Comment: `LocalDateTime logoutTime = LocalDateTime.now();` is where the variable is.

Comment: the `dtf` one is from `private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: Thanks for adding information. It’s always better to edit the question and add the information there so we have everything in one place (you may then just add a comment here to make us aware of your edit). I’d really like to help, but you still haven’t given us something we can reproduce, and in your code I can’t see where you are setting `loginTime` (as I understand the variable that has the wrong value).

Comment: Maybe the best thing you can do is learn to use your debugger.

Comment: the `loginTime` is the same as `logoutTime`, which is `LocalDateTime logoutTime = LocalDateTime.now();`

Comment: thanks, I'll try to use the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you haven't provided the whole code, i can only guess that what

```
 timeouttf.setText(dtf.format(logoutTime));
```

this line does is take the stored time in predefined variable and set it as log out time.

If you want to get current time when you press logout then you should reset the value of logoutTime variable with the new time.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I don't know what code that reset the value of logoutTime

Comment: then you change the value for logoutTime and generate new Value when you are setting the value in       timeouttf.setText(dtf.format(logoutTime));

Comment: I just edited the post to see where my value of `logoutTime` and `loginTime`. Please refer to it. I still don't know how to change the value.

Comment: LocalDateTime logoutTime = LocalDateTime.now();.   This line should not be placed right next to login time.     Move this line to  line above timeouttf.setText. Line